# Restoring all GUI items to their default size / positions in NetBeans

Tags: netbeans

I was wondering if there was a quick key combination in NetBeans to get the various GUI items placed on it back to their default sizes and something approaching a default position. I ask because, when swapping between Layouts / playing with NetBeans / trying to get the various items to display properly, they have the odd tendency to teleport to places I cannot find, or change size to something less than useful. Admittedly, this is quite annoying, when you have more than a few items in a form, and have to use the Navigator to find out whether the damn thing even still exists!

Answer (score 23):

You can use the `Window > Reset Windows` menu item. This will reset the IDE's GUI back to the default state.

Answer (score 6):

Use the `Help>About` menu to find the `User Directory`. Then navigate to it and delete directory `config>Windows2Local`. Restart the IDE and you will have the default windows settings. (The deleted dir will be recreated by netbeans)

Comment: Wait, this will reset just the single frame I am editing, or all of them?

Comment: this will restore all IDE gui to their default place

Comment: You can delete the **<UserDir>/config/Windows2Local** directory instead. - NetBeans will recreate it on startup. Deleting the whole user directory will also delete the cache that the IDE has built up - which is used to improve the startup time, any database connections you have stored, personal preferences, ect.